# Passing std::vector of std::shared_ptr, not updating the objects

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

Okay, I may be doing this wrong, but I am at my wits end.

I have a vector of shared_ptr of my node class that I pass around for various things, my node class has a vector of share_ptr of it neighbors of type node.

I have a class that generates the mesh of nodes for me, and returns a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> nodes`, and a significant `std::shared_ptr<Node> significant node`.
I then pass this vector into an indexer that creates a second list that is a subset of the first of about 10% the size, which it returns as `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> indexedNodes`.

After these are created, I pass them into another object that keeps them for later reference.
Then a modifier class gets the a single random node from the indexedNodes, and uses that to walk through the node neighbors modifying a height value.

Later, when I go to export these out, the values show up as 0/initialized.

Somethings to note, I pass the data into the functions and return with just `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>` which I figured is my issue, I am just not sure how to properly pass a container of my shared_ptr so that I don't make copies.

If more info is needed, let me know. I am looking for an example or a reference that I can understand.

Sorry for the code, it is not beautful, and I have it using Dynamically Loaded Libraries.

The function where the work is done:

```
void cruthu::Cruthu::Run() {
    std::shared_ptr<cruthu::ITeraGen> teraGen(this->mSettings.TeraGen.Factory->DLGetInstance());
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>> nodes(teraGen->Create());
    std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node> significantNode(teraGen->GetSignificantNode());

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::IIndexer>> indexers;
    for(const auto indexer : this->mSettings.Indexers) {
        indexers.push_back(indexer.Factory->DLGetInstance());
    }
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>> indexedNodes(indexers.at(0)->Index(nodes));

    std::shared_ptr<cruthu::ITera> tera(this->mSettings.Tera.Factory->DLGetInstance());
    tera->SetNodes(nodes);
    tera->SetIndexedNodes(indexedNodes);
    tera->SetSignificantNode(significantNode);

    for(const auto & formaF : this->mSettings.Formas) {
        std::shared_ptr<cruthu::IForma> forma(formaF.Factory->DLGetInstance());
        forma->SetNode(tera->GetIndexedNode());
        forma->Modify();

        std::cout << std::to_string(tera->GetIndexedNode()->GetHeight()) << std::endl;
    }

    this->CreateImage(tera);
}
```

TeraGen:

```
#ifndef CRUTHU_ITERAGEN_HPP
#define CRUTHU_ITERAGEN_HPP

#include <cruthu/Node.hpp>

#include <vector>

namespace cruthu {
class ITeraGen {
public:
    virtual ~ITeraGen() = default;

    virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>> Create() = 0;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node> GetSignificantNode() = 0;
};
} // namespace cruthu
#endif
```

Tera:

```
#ifndef CRUTHU_ITERA_HPP
#define CRUTHU_ITERA_HPP

#include <cruthu/IIndexer.hpp>
#include <cruthu/Node.hpp>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace cruthu {
class ITera {
public:
    virtual ~ITera() = default;

    virtual void SetNodes(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>>& nodes) = 0;
    virtual void SetIndexedNodes(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>>& indexedNodes) = 0;
    virtual void SetSignificantNode(std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node> significantNode) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>>& GetNodes() = 0;
    virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>>& GetIndexedNodes() = 0;
    virtual std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node> GetIndexedNode() = 0;
};
} // namespace cruthu
#endif
```

Indexer:

```
#ifndef CRUTHU_IINDEXER_HPP
#define CRUTHU_IINDEXER_HPP

#include <cruthu/Node.hpp>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

namespace cruthu {
class IIndexer {
public:
    virtual ~IIndexer() = default;

    virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>> Index(std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node> node) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>> Index(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>>& nodes) = 0;
};
} // namespace cruthu
#endif
```

Forma:

```
#ifndef CRUTHU_IFORMA_HPP
#define CRUTHU_IFORMA_HPP

#include <cruthu/Node.hpp>

namespace cruthu {
class IForma {
public:
    virtual ~IForma() = default;

    virtual void SetNode(std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node> node) = 0;
    virtual void Modify() = 0;
};
} // namespace cruthu
#endif
```

I did update and try adding references in in between, which is why they now have references in places. I still have the same issue.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing exactly what you are actually doing, and what you are having trouble with

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that you're duplicating nodes somewhere.

Comment: I will get a MCVE soon.

Comment: With shared_ptrs, unless I call std::copy with it, I dont duplicate correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get it going with the comments from above, this is mainly my problem of not being able to provide adequate information.
With that said, I re-worked the code to instead pass a `cruthu::Tera` object around as a shared pointer and exposed the vectors as public members of the class. This is something I will revisit at a later date, as this implementation is not something I feel happy about.

The code is on [github](https://github.com/Vi1i/cruthu), unfortunately it is my thesis work, so I could no longer wait.

If people feel the desire to still attempt an answer, I will work with them.

Answer (score 0):

As user `Remy Lebeau` stated please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

As you stated you are passing a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>>` around from one class to another or from one function to another and that they are not updating and are 0 initialized. From the behavior that you are describing I then have a question for you, I'm posting this as an answer as it would be too long for a comment.

Does your function declaration/definition that accepts the vector or shared pointers above look something like this:

```
void someFunc( std::vector<shared_ptr<Node> nodes ) { ... }
```

or does it look something like this:

```
void someFunc( std::vector<shared_ptr<Node>& nodes ) { ... }
```

I ask this because it makes a difference if you are passing the container around by value as opposed to by reference.

Comment: Thanks, I will soon. The first one is what I am passing around as.

Comment: @Vi1i I think that may be your issue; try passing the vector as a reference instead!

Comment: I posted the code, can you check it out and see if it looks right?

Answer (score 0):

This is not (yet) a answer, but questions to pin down the problem, since not enough implementation is provided.

One possible problem (hard to say without seeing the implementation...) is that you create the nodes in top of the `Run()` function:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<cruthu::Node>> nodes(teraGen->Create());
```

Then you pass that function as reference in this call:

```
tera->SetNodes(nodes);
```

What does tera do with the nodes? Passing by reference means that the count of the shared_ptr:s isn't incremented.

what does `this->CreateImage(tera)` do?

Are the nodes used after `Run()` has finished?

Comment: I see you visited the git repo, I made some changes on how I passed things around in general. So I am going to post what I did and accept that as the answer...